# Assistance with simple JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have got a problem in selecting the employees name from employees table(empID) which is primary key and from consignation table based on two foreign key 1- consignee and 2- hand over by ( these two fields have relation with empID) so is it possible to select consignee and handoverby not by ID but based on Employees name(emp.name). Please write the query, thanks in adv.

Comment: This isn't really a place where we just "write your query." If you show us sample data, desired results, what you've tried and how it didn't work, people will likely be much more willing and able to help. [Please read this](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can use `INNER JOIN` if both column from `consignation` table are non-nullable. But if one is *nullable*, you need to use `LEFT JOIN` so records from `consignation` will still be shown on the list.

```
SELECT  con.EmpName AS consigneeName,
        ho.EmpName AS handOverName
FROM    consignation a
        INNER JOIN employee con
            ON a.ConSignee = con.empID
        INNER JOIN employee ho
            ON a.handoverby = ho.empID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: +1 for interpreting. But almost -1 for making my comment look bad. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand please don't scold me again `:D` hehe

Comment: Thanks guys for replying the question, let me provide you more information about this problem, the fields of consignation table are : conID, ConSignee(foreign key with empID), handoverby(foreign key with empID) and employees table: EmpID(pk), empname and ....

Comment: @user2202527 did you try to execute the query above?

Comment: So I want to select from consignation table two fields(consignee and handoverby) not the Id of employees but their names.

Comment: the query above will give the names of the employees not the ID. If you have tried to execute the query, you'll see the result.

Comment: Thanks brother, have a good time. Can you give me your Skype name or anything to be in-touched with you ?

Comment: I just have to laugh at the request for the personal contact info... Sure, I'll become your personal 24x7 help line (NOT).